# How to have system properties in SQL Server database table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure mobile database with few tables which have columns `id, _CreatedAt, _UpdatedAt` by default.

I deployed my local SQL Server database to Azure and I'm expecting the same features (`id, _CreatedAt, _UpdatedAt`) in my tables.

Is there any way to do that without writing triggers?

Comment: The `id` can be handled by an `int identity` column, the `_CreatedAt` column can have a default constraint of `sysdatetime()`, but for the `_UpdatedAt` column, I don't think there's any other way than a trigger (or setting the value programmatically in your application and then just storing it)

Comment: Sorry. I don't think you will have that out of the box.